# Array.prototype.filter não funciona da maneira esperada

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer uma validação de campos utilizando o método Array.prototype.filter(), mas não parece surtir efeito:

```
<script>
    function isEmpty() {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = 
            Array.prototype.filter.call(
                Array.prototype.slice.call(
                    document.getElementsByClassName("input")),
                        function(input) {
                            input.value != "";
                        });
    }
</script>
<form>
    <input class="input" onkeydown="isEmpty()" onkeyup="isEmpty()">
    <input class="input" onkeydown="isEmpty()" onkeyup="isEmpty()">
    <input class="input" onkeydown="isEmpty()" onkeyup="isEmpty()">
    <input class="input" onkeydown="isEmpty()" onkeyup="isEmpty()">
    <button id="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

O que era para ocorrer, é o botão ficar habilitado apenas quando todos os campos estiverem preenchidos, mas não é o que acontece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Três coisas que deves mudar no teu código:

#1 - o método filter tem de ter dentro da função callback um `return`. Ou seja em vez de somente `input.value != "";`  deves ter `return input.value != "";`

#2 - quando usas o método filter tens de ler a propriedade `.length` para saber se há valores dentro do resultado. Como o [hugomg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92671/129) referiu uma array vazia valida como `true`, então deves usar `.length` para saber se a array de facto está vazia.

#3 - quando usas `Array.prototype.filter.call(lista, callback);` já não precisas de usar o `.slice`. Podes remover essa linha.

Assim o código corrigido e mais organizado poderia ser assim:

```
function isEmpty() {
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
    var empty =  Array.prototype.filter.call(inputs, function (input) {
        return input.value.trim() == "";
    });
    submit.disabled = !!empty.length;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0vy3fgc/

Comment: Sobre o return, eu esqueci de colocar aqui na postagem. Já o `.slice`, não seria necessário, já que o `getElementsByClassName` retorna um array-like e o `.filter` trabalha com arrays?

Comment: @Patrick o `Array.prototype.filter` vai tratar essa lista de nós do DOM como uma array e daí o slice não ser necessário.

Answer (score 2):

O método filter retorna uma lista e listas em Javascript sempre contam como "verdadeiro" em um contexto booleano (inclusive a lsita vazia).

```
if( [] ){
    console.log("Olá!");
}else{
    connsole.log("Esse else nunca roda");
}
```

No entanto, acho que o método [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) se encaixa melhor no que você quer fazer do que o `filter`.

Comment: Uai, mas `[] == false` não dá `true`?

Comment: Nunca confie no operador de `==` de Javascript :) Ele faz umas [conversões de tipos bem malucas](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) e quase sempre é melhor usar o `===` ao invés dele.

Comment: Coloquei o `every`, porém agora ele habilita o botão a primeira entrada e mesmo que eu apague, continua habilitado. Será que é algum problema com o `slice` ou `getElementsByClassName`?